# Constract DF from a logical DF and a Boolean DF

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, combinations

I have two DF 
the folowing one is Boolean

```
> Portfolio 1 

Name | X1992 | X1993 | X1994 
XHHD   False   False   True
Jdqd   False   False   False
Jhds   False   True    False
lkaz   False   False   True                      
nqb    True    False   False
jbqs   False   False   False
jbq    False   True    False
knd    True    False   True
njvd   False   True    False
kjiz   True    False   True
khza   False   False   False
akhd   False   False   True
jkaze  True    True    False
bzae   True    False   False
```

the Second DF have a monthly frequence

> Return

```
Name | 1992/01 | 1992/02 ..... 1994/12 
XHHD   0.23       0.564
Jdqd   0.3        0.654
Jhds   0.234      0.456
lkaz   0.54       0.472               
nqb    0.99       0.761
jbqs   0.01       1.765
jbq    0.23       0.002
knd    0.59       2.32
njvd   0.123      0.43
kjiz   0.987      -0.12
khza   1.34       0.12
akhd   0.76       0.23
jkaze  0.654      0.98
bzae   0.43       0.73
```

I want to have a DF that calculte me the mean monthly return of companies based on the boolean DF if the Companies TRUE then include her return on the calculaion. 
the results will be

```
Date     Portfolio 1
1992/01   mean
1992/02   mean
1992/03   mean
1992/04   mean
```

Comment: please use `dput` to make your examples reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this by converting to 'long' format, do a join and then get the `mean` by 'Date'

```
library(data.table)
dM1 <- melt(setDT(df1), id.var = "Name")
na.omit(melt(setDT(df2), id.var = "Name", variable.name = "Date")[,
     variable := paste0("X", substring(Date, 1, 4))
      ][dM1, on = .(Name, variable)
       ][i.value == "True", .(Portfolio = mean(value, na.rm = TRUE)) , Date])
#     Date  Portfolio  
#1: 1992/01    0.7302
#2: 1992/02    0.9342
```

#### data

```
 df1 <- structure(list(Name = c("XHHD", "Jdqd", "Jhds", "lkaz", "nqb", 
"jbqs", "jbq", "knd", "njvd", "kjiz", "khza", "akhd", "jkaze", 
"bzae"), X1992 = c("False", "False", "False", "False", "True", 
"False", "False", "True", "False", "True", "False", "False", 
"True", "True"), X1993 = c("False", "False", "True", "False", 
"False", "False", "True", "False", "True", "False", "False", 
"False", "True", "False"), X1994 = c("True", "False", "False", 
"True", "False", "False", "False", "True", "False", "True", "False", 
"True", "False", "False")), .Names = c("Name", "X1992", "X1993", 
"X1994"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -14L))

df2 <-  structure(list(Name = c("XHHD", "Jdqd", "Jhds", "lkaz", "nqb", 
"jbqs", "jbq", "knd", "njvd", "kjiz", "khza", "akhd", "jkaze", 
"bzae"), `1992/01` = c(0.23, 0.3, 0.234, 0.54, 0.99, 0.01, 0.23, 
0.59, 0.123, 0.987, 1.34, 0.76, 0.654, 0.43), `1992/02` = c(0.564, 
0.654, 0.456, 0.472, 0.761, 1.765, 0.002, 2.32, 0.43, -0.12, 
0.12, 0.23, 0.98, 0.73)), .Names = c("Name", "1992/01", "1992/02"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -14L))
```

Comment: thank you arkun for your answer, but there is somthing rang in the out put. 
It look like below

Comment: Thank you arkun for your answer. But there is a somthing rang cause the output look like this Names = c("Name", "variable", "value"), row.names = c(NA, 
-68088L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: (nil)>) and if I change the place of two DF in the cood it appears Names = c("Name", "variable", "value"), row.names = c(NA, 
-68088L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: (nil)>)
just I want Names =c("Date", Portfolio1)